# Axios/Fetch not using next.config.js rewrite

Tags: reactjs, axios, next.js, proxy

Looking up several examples online, it appears all one would need to do to redirect requests to the backend is to add rewrites to the next.config.js file, and it should work. However, I must be missing or misunderstanding something as this alone doesn't seem to do the trick. Redirecting seems to work if I type the url in the browser, but calls from axios/fetch continue to try to use a path relative to my client. Here are my snippets:

**next.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api',
        destination: 'http://localhost:3001',
      },
    ]
  },
};
```

**components/MyComponent.js**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function MyComponent({projectName}) {
    ...
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get("/api/project/" + projectName)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
        
        return;
    }, []);
    ...
};

export default MyComponent;
```

To clarify, if I hit `http://localhost:8001/api/project/Name_of_Project` from the browser, I get properly redirected to my server (hosted on port 3001) and receive data I'd expect. However, when I hit my client (`http://localhost:8001/Name_of_Project`), axios doesn't redirect and tries `http://localhost:8001/api/project/Name_of_Project` which obviously fails. I also tried the `fetch` equivalent instead of axios and get the same result.

Is there another step that I need to take? Does the rewrite not work for axios/fetch? I have also seen mentions of the `next-http-proxy-middleware` package in my search, but I am not sure if this is something that I need to use in conjunction with the rewrite or not.

I appreciate any insight!

<s>**EDIT 1:**
After doing some more searching, I ran into this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47576071/react-not-using-proxy-server), and discovered that my issue is because I am using relative pathing in my axios call. If I change it to:</s>

```
axios.get("http://localhost:3001/api/project/" + projectName)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    });
```

then I get my data properly. I suppose this leads me to my next question: is there a way to use relative path alongside the rewrite in the config? I personally think it's a little ugly to have the hostname and port exposed like that (I eventually plan on hosting this app on a FQDN). So if there's anything that can be done about that, I'd love to know!

**EDIT 2**: Of course the change in my first edit works because I am hitting my server directly! Which is not the desired effect. I want to use the redirect set in the config to go to my api.

Comment: My server is not telling my client anything. I am trying to proxy my requests from the client to the server.

Comment: I think we might have been talking past each other, but I still found the answer to my question, which I posted. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I WAS misunderstanding something. I assumed that the path in the rewrite would reattached my path params for free. This is not the case. A [link](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites#wildcard-path-matching) to the documentation.

The relevant excerpt:

> Wildcard Path Matching
>
> To match a wildcard path you can use * after a parameter, for example /blog/:slug* will match /blog/a/b/c/d/hello-world:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/blog/:slug*',
        destination: '/news/:slug*', // Matched parameters can be used in the destination
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

So my corrected `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/:slug*',
        destination: 'http://localhost:3001/api/:slug*',
      },
    ]
  },
};
```